# How to combine 2 key for localizable

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

I have a localizable string file that contains

```
"please" = "Please";
"try.again" = "try again.";
```

Inside my application, i would like to use

```
"please" = "Please";
"try.again" = "try again.";
```

at the same time for making one sentence = $please + $try.again = `Please try again.`

So, I have tried this approach

```
+ (NSString *)pleaseLocalizedString {
return NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"please", @"Localizable",[Bundle bundle], @"Please button");
}

+ (NSString *)tryAgainLocalizedString {
return NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"try.again", @"Localizable",[Bundle bundle], @"try again button");
}
```

But with this way again I have to use `stringWithFormat` to combine these two methods to make one sentence...
How can I make this in an easy way? Any idea?

Comment: Y you have to isolate them ???

Comment: Why do you want to use two separate localizable strings? I’d suggest using one instead - otherwise you may get into trouble for some languages: no guarantees that “please” should be the first word in the sentence in any language.

Comment: Hello, because i will have too many strings start with `please`, so i woul like to use it as less as possible. Do u have any idea to make it? @algrid @Sh_Khan

Comment: There is no such thing as "too many string that start with please". You have string that need to be localized. The number doesn't matter. Do it properly up front and save yourself a lot of work later.

Comment: You should have a read through https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/string-localization/ Localization is a place where "refactoring" is _not_ a good idea. You can't assume that there is a 1-to-1 mapping between English words or constructs and their translations. See the "String Key Best Practices" heading in that article for an excellent example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not attempt to combine two separate individually localized strings into one string. Correct sentence formation is not easily generalized across languages. Some languages are right-to-left, while others are left-to-right. Also, certain words may have different meaning when combined, especially in languages like Chinese.

If you need "please" separately in some places and you need "try again" separately in some other places, and you need "please try again" separately in other different places then use three different keys for the three different strings.

If you only need "please try again" and you don't need "please" or "try again" separately, then only have the one key for "please try again".

Having said that, the solution to your question as asked would be to define a third string as:

```
"p.t.a" = "%1$@ %2$@";
```

Then in some other localization the right side could be something like `"%2$@, %1$@";`.

Then you would have:

```
+ (NSString *)pleaseTryAgainLocalizedString {
    NSString *format = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"p.t.a", @"Localizable",[Bundle bundle], @"Please Try Again");
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:format, [self pleaseLocalizedString], [self tryAgainLocalizedString]];
}
```

But again, this is just silly. Simply define:

```
"please.try.again" = "Please try again.";
```

and:

```
+ (NSString *)pleaseTryAgainLocalizedString {
    return NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"please.try.again", @"Localizable",[Bundle bundle], @"Please Try Again");
}
```

This gives you the most flexibility for translating this string into any other language.